# what happen to B-frames?! MP4Box evalvid , JM .264

Tags: video, mp4, h.264, encoder, mp4box

I encode an HD video (Beauty.yuv) by JM with IBBBPBBBPBBBP... pattern.

then to convert output.264 to out.mp4 by MP4Box do this:

MP4Box -profile high -hint -mtu 1024 -fps 30 -add output.264 out.mp4

then I make .st file:

./mp4trace -f -s 192.168.0.2 12346 out.mp4 > st_a01.st

but my st file look like:

1   I   142647  140 0.075

2   P   82493   81  0.202

3   P   24373   24  0.204

4   P   29224   29  0.204

5   P   23495   23  0.204

6   P   76393   75  0.331

7   P   22832   23  0.331

8   P   25367   25  0.336

9   P   22635   23  0.336

10  P   120039  118 0.469

11  P   24255   24  0.469

12  P   26783   27  0.469

13  P   23338   23  0.469

14  P   96223   94  0.596

15  P   22626   23  0.602

16  P   25306   25  0.602

17  P   26856   27  0.602

18  P   99348   98  0.729

19  P   25576   25  0.735

20  P   32550   32  0.736

21  P   28752   29  0.736

22  P   110795  109 0.869

23  P   23601   24  0.869

24  P   25118   25  0.869

25  P   24258   24  0.869

26  P   87966   86  0.991

27  P   21435   21  1.002

there is no B-frame or B-slice in packets ! 
why that happen ?
what is wrong here ?

thanks for your attention

Comment: When you say _"st file"_ do you mean TS (`.ts`) file? Otherwise provide a link to info about `.st` video fomat...

Comment: no I mean .st file. is a file cntain information about video file that we want to stream in network simulator. simulatores like ns2 take it and anothere file ".dat" , and simulate streaming on them.

Answer (score 0):

> What happen to B-frames?... Why this happen? What is wrong here?

It's possible that MP4Box is encoding your H264 video by using the **Baseline** profile.

Check it with a tool like **[MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download)**. Only **Main** and **High** profiles support B-frames (aka B-slices).

[image]
(image from : StreamingLearningCenter.com's **[article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160620054333/http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com:80/articles/producing-h264-video-for-flash-an-overview.html?page=2)**)

Comment: yes , mp4box used baseline profile 
and caused this problem

thank you VC.One

Comment: Today I execute "MP4Box -info out.mp4", and I see that high profile is in use. problem is not about profile

Comment: Can you provide a link to short samples of both `mp4` file and `st` file? Why are you doing `-info out.mp4`? Why check some other MP4 file when your Questions **actually says** the P-frames happen when you do this : _**"..then I make .st file:"**_ and your result is _**"but my st file look like:"** (meaning all P frames). I'm not familiar with `.st` video format (only know `.TS`). Can you be sure that both your `mp4` and this `st` file have exact same encoding setup? Does the **mp4 file** itself have no B-frames?

Comment: How can I check that what is the type of frames in mp4 file ?

Comment: This link contain information about evalvid and st file http://www2.tkn.tu-berlin.de/research/evalvid/EvalVid/docevalvid.html

Comment: _"How can I check that what is the type of frames in mp4 file?"_ right, I thought you were a programmer in charge of the input data. You have to parse the H.264 video inside that mp4 container. Extract it (not re-encode mp4 to h.264). Use FFmpeg like `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy video.h264`, then use a freeware h.264 analysis tool to check frames (web search for preferred tool). Type is in each h.264 frame header. Or, in mp4 file, check bytes via _hex editor_ tool. Go to section `stss` (it lists the keyframes) and see if every frame is a keyframe (check offsets, if key follows key in bytes).

Comment: Anyways I gave you a correct answer. If there are only P-frames then your H264 is encoded as **Baseline**. That is how MPEG encoding works. An encoder must go for best compression, it would never deliberately make "expensive" P-frames for every frame unless forced to by the encoding **profile**. This fact remains regardless whether your M4Box tool is changing data between your `.st` and `.mp4` file. Are your `.st` output settings affecting this at all? (did/can you force each frame to be marked as keyframe within output bytes?).

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `MP4Box -info out.mp4`, you'll get some general information on the file.

If you execute `MP4Box -info 1 out.mp4`, you'll get some more specific information about the track 1 of the file.

If you execute `MP4Box -diso out.mp4`, you'll get a detailed XML (including the timings) of your MP4 file structure.

Maybe another precision about "I/P/B-frames". Since H264 (2003), there are only I/P/B slices, which makes your verification a little harder (since you need to check slices and not frames).

Also MP4Box is only a muxer, it won't modify the semantics of your encoded content.

Comment: I execute "MP4Box -info out.mp4", and I see that high profile is in use. but where is my problem? why packets in  .st file dont have B lable ! and seems they are all P-type ?

Comment: I don't know about mp4trace, I am a MP4Box maintainer.