# B-frames in evalvid and MP4Box

Tags: video, mp4, h.264, encoder, mp4box

becaus of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673937/what-happen-to-b-frames-mp4box-evalvid-jm-264) I need to change the profile in MP4Box to "high" or "main".
how can I do that ?

I try :
MP4Box -profile main -hint -mtu 1024 -fps 30 -add a01.m4v a01.mp4

But it dont work, and I dont have B-frames in final step.

How can I have B-frames after execute evalvid cammands (MP4Box , mp4trace)??

Any tips can be useful

Answer (score 1):

MP4Box is not an encoder, it is a muxer. So you need to re-encode your content using the JM or FFmpeg/libx264.

Comment: I need  produced .mp4 file for streaming the video over a network simulator. my next step is to prepare it for streaming by "./mp4trace -f -s 192.168.0.2 12346 out.mp4 > st_a01.st" command.

Comment: I think maybe re-encoding content by JM damage RTP tracks produced by MP4Box. dont you ?

Comment: Correct. The encoding occurs before the packaging.